# How to convert this mongo query to pymongo code?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have wrote some mongo query. but I can't use this query in pymongo.

I tried to use "$lookup" but my mongo version is 3.4, and it doesn't support pipeline. So I wrote queries. But I have no idea to store query results to mongodb 'var' in python.

```
var user_ids = db.register.find({
        "$and": [
            {"_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5d0a4df00000000000000000")}}
            ,{"_id": {"$lt": ObjectId("5d0b9f700000000000000000")}}
    ]}).map(function(register){
        return register.user_id;
        });

db.login.find({
        "$and": [
            {"_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5d0b9f700000000000000000")}}
            ,{"_id": {"$lt": ObjectId("5d0cf0f00000000000000000")}}
            ,{"user_id": {"$in": user_ids}}
    ]});

I wanna convert those queries to python code(pymongo).
```

Answer (score 0):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_find.asp) you can create queries like so

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

for x in mycol.find({},{ "_id": 0, "name": 1, "address": 1 }):
  print(x)
```

so in your case it would be along the lines of:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

user_ids = db.register.find({},{
    "$and": [
        {"_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5d0a4df00000000000000000")}}
        ,{"_id": {"$lt": ObjectId("5d0b9f700000000000000000")}}
]}).map(function(register){
    return register.user_id;
    });

db.login.find({}, $and": [
            {"_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5d0b9f700000000000000000")}}
            ,{"_id": {"$lt": ObjectId("5d0cf0f00000000000000000")}}
            ,{"user_id": {"$in": user_ids}}
    ]}
```

You also do not need the `var` in python. As in python you do not need to declare the variable type.

Comment: Thx, Jack. But those two queries are related. 'user_ids' variable contains results of first query(and it's count is about millons). Then it is parameter for $in clause at second query.

Comment: Try that now please